# Of no subject is this more than administrative law

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence

What is the sentence structure of the above sentence?
Does it mean “No subject is of more than true than administrative law”?

Comment: Sorry! A word missing in the sentence being question. It should be “Of no subject is this more true than administrative law”. Thx so much

Comment: This is not a truer subject than administrative law?

Comment: Hello and welcome. About the missing word - unless it invalidates an answer, the recommended practice here is to [edit] the question directly to put the word in. Comments aren’t guaranteed to be read as part of the question.

Comment: This is more true of administrative law than it is of any other subject.

Answer (score 2):

> Of no subject is this more true than administrative law

Because this sentence is out of context, it is difficult to accurately explain the true meaning of "this" in relationship to administrative law or any other subject.  That said, whatever "this" refers to may be somewhat true with other subjects, but is most true in relation to administrative law.

As to sentence structure, this is a copular inversion. The verb "is" links the subject to the prepositional phrase at the start of the sentence.